# Confusion regarding the forces acting on a block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

[image]

This is the arrangement of the blocks. All surfaces are frictionless.

My first confusion is will the block $M$ exert a normal force on the hanging block $m$? I don't think so, but still wanted to get it clear.

Coming to my main confusion, the movement of the blocks....
Here's what I think: the block M will move leftward due to the normal force from the pulley. The block m will move right wrt block M. But what about the hanging block? In the ground frame, will it move leftwards (along with block M)? Common sense says so, but the 2 forces acting on the block are both in the vertical direction, so how can it have horizontal acceleration?

Comment: Only one of the forces on the "vertically" hanging block is always truly vertical: gravity. Hint: I used quotes around a term in the preceding sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-inertial reference frame, a pendulum in an accelerating car](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653590/)