# Find the maximum height reached by an accelerated pendulum using energy conservation in an inertial frame of reference

Tags: reference-frames, energy-conservation, inertial-frames

Given a pendulum in an accelerated frame of reference (for the left) the goal is to find the maximum height *H* reached by the pendulum in its equilibrium. See the following image:

[image]

A simple approach is to consider a non-inertial force $\vec{a}$ and the change of kinetic energy will be equal to the work realized by the field forces, so $\Delta E_c = 0 = |\vec{a}|X -|\vec{g}|H$ and from this we can take $H$.

[image]

Note that we cannot confuse the above condition of instantaneous rest with one of static equilibrium. In fact, the above equation can also be found by comparing the momentum in the initial position of the pendulum caused by the resultant force with that caused by the other forces. I have done this in the following picture:

[image]

My question, however, is how can the above reasoning be replicated in the inertial frame of reference? We know from previous [discussions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645938/why-does-a-pendulum-bob-which-is-hanged-to-the-ceiling-of-a-car-go-backwards-whe) that in an inertial frame of reference the pendulum is at rest until the string tension is sufficient to initiate a horizontal motion. So, if there is no motion, is it possible to consider the work of the forces in the surround of the pendulum?

[image]

Comment: The easiest method in the inertial frame is to simply draw a free-body diagram for the pendulum bob and show that if it is accelerating horizontally then the tension force must be at a particular angle.  I've never seen this energy technique that you're describing (I'm not even 100% sure it's correct) and I have no idea how/whether it would generalize to an inertial frame.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure your energy method is incorrect.  If you have $|\vec{a}| = |\vec{g}|$ then your method predicts $X = H$, i.e. the pendulum is horizontal.  But in actuality you should get a 45° angle with the horizontal, with $X = (\sqrt{2} + 1) H$.

Comment: I am aware of the equilibrium idea. For the second statement you can restrict $|\vec{a}|$ < $|\vec{g}|$ and we are ok.

Comment: It still doesn't work even if $|\vec{a}| < |\vec{g}|$.  For $|\vec{a}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} |\vec{g}|$ the equilibrium method yields a 30° angle to the vertical, or $H/X = 2 - \sqrt{3} ≈ 0.2679...$  Your energy method yields $H/X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} ≈ 0.5774...$.  More generally, the equilibrium method yields $a/g = \tan \theta$, while your energy method yields $a/g = (1 - \cos \theta)/\sin \theta = \tan (\theta/2)$.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSeifert, after thinking about it for a few days, I understand my mistake. In the above discussion we confused the concepts of instantaneous rest and static equilibrium. In the above situation the pendulum is not at rest with a person in the car. I got the same equation as before (using the energy method) by considering the momentum caused by the resultant force in the initial position of the pendulum. See my edited question.